# postgresql get the closest result of timestemp

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, where-clause

I'm using Postgres 11, and I have this query:

```
SELECT start_date 
from connection_history 
where connection_name='myclient' 
 and start_date='2020-03-04 10:46:30';
```

But it doesn't catch the result as it looks like that:

```
         start_date
----------------------------
 2020-03-04 10:46:30.071+00
```

How can i catch the result without adding the ending ? 
I tried with `LIKE` and it didn't work:

```
SELECT start_date 
from connection_history 
where connection_name='myclient' 
and start_date LIKE '2020-03-04 10:46:30%';
```

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone ~~ unknown
LINE 1: ...ection_name='myclient' and start_date LIKE '2020...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

**EDIT:**
I need something like this:

```
start_date > '2020-03-04 10:46:30' + interval '30 seconds';
```

**EDIT2:**

```
SELECT start_date 
from connection_history 
where connection_name='myclient' 
and start_date between ('2020-03-04 10:46:30' - interval '30 seconds') 
                   and ('2020-03-04 10:46:30' + interval '30 seconds');
```

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type interval: "2020-03-04 10:46:30"
LINE 1: ...me='myclient' and start_date between ('2020-03-0...
```

**Ended up using it like the answer:**

```
SELECT start_date from connection_history where connection_name='myclient' and start_date <= timestamp '2020-03-04 10:46:30' + interval '2 seconds';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
start_date between timestamp '2020-03-04 10:46' - interval '30 seconds'
               and timestamp '2020-03-04 10:46' + interval '30 seconds'
```

If you want to make writing that easier, you can create a function that creates a [range type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) with the middle being a passed timestamp around a given interval

```
create function create_range(p_middle timestamp, p_length interval)
  returns tsrange
as
$$
  select tsrange(p_middle - p_length / 2,  p_middle + p_length / 2, '[]');
$$
immutable
language sql;
```

Then you can do the following:

```
where start_date <@ create_range(timestamp '2020-03-04 10:46', interval '1 minute');
```

However, this won't use an (B-Tree) index on `start_date` - if you need that, you will need to use the `between` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
 start_date >= '2020-03-04 10:46:30+00' and start_date < '2020-03-04 10:46:31+00'
```

Comment: I need a way to work like `LIKE` statment, is there a way ? or like to tell it to look for +- 30 seconds ?

Comment: Just specify the number of seconds using `interval`: `between (start_date - interval '30 seconds') and (start_date + interval '30 seconds')`

Comment: @pensnarik Hey please look at my edit2, it didnt work or more likely is that im using it wrong.

Comment: @gsr cast it to `timestamptz` explicitly: `between ('2020-03-04 10:46:30'::timestamptz - interval '30 seconds') and ('2020-03-04 10:46:30'::timestamptz + interval '30 seconds')`